# Is it possible to use a custom alert message in all pages by designing it in a single page in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application,there are nearly 45 pages. I want to display an alert message(customized) in all pages of my application. Is it possible to design it in a single page and call it in other pages?

Xaml design for alert message:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ExpiryPopUp_Container" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" Width="800" Height="768">
    <Canvas x:Name="ExpiryPopUp" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Height="180" Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="320" Grid.Row="1" Width="300">
        <Canvas Background="{StaticResource LeftNavBackground}" Height="48" Width="300">
            <TextBlock FontSize="26" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans Regular" Text="Alert" Width="300" Canvas.Top="10" Height="28"/>
        </Canvas>
        <TextBlock Text=" Session has expired." FontSize="22" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans Regular" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource BlueText}" Canvas.Top="71" Width="300"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="OkButton" Background="{StaticResource buttonBackground}" Height="32" Width="56" Canvas.Left="122" Canvas.Top="120" Tap="OkButton_Tap">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="Ok" FontSize="24" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans Regular" Width="49" Height="26" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Left="3"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Can't you make it a UserControl and then display it in a Popup?

Comment: @yasen I made a usercontrol and on canvas i created Tap event. In this event i want to write NaviagionService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative)); But its not accepting Navigation?How to navigate to another page once user tap on a canvas defined in UserControl>

Comment: @yasen its giving error, if am writing NavigationService.Navigate.

Comment: @yasen Its only accepting NavigationService.Equals and NavigationService.ReferenceEquals

Comment: I see. When used in a page `NavigationService` means a property of the page class, which is an object of the class with the same name. In a UserControl, there is not such property and so `NavigationService` is considered to be the class itself (which does not have a static Navigate method). To navigate from a UserControl, use this: `((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(...);`

Comment: @eX0du5 Hi, can u share your code for usercontrol popup which behaves as toast message please.

Comment: Was the last comment aimed @me? Anyway, I don't have such code. I just think that's the way to do it. It should work. Create a Popup, set its `Child` to be the UserControl that you want to show and then set the Popup's `IsOpen` property to true.

Comment: @yasen last comment is for someone else. sorry and your answer is working. To navigate from a UserControl, use this: ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(...);

Comment: @yasen I am using this usercontrol in almost all pages, But in some pages Tap event has to navigate to some other page. I mean to say functionality of OkButton Tap is different. So how can we achieve this by using a usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

Per above comments, you want to navigate. To do that from anywhere in your app, you can do:

```
(App.Current as App).RootFrame.Navigate(...)
```

I would caution against using a Canvas (anywhere!) becuase if you ever move to being a Universal App (Windows and Windows Phone 8.1) all your layout will be wrong on [larger-screen devices](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/22/taking-advantage-of-large-screen-windows-phones/). Or even if you decide to support landscape orientation, for that matter.

Un-parented popups won't rotate with the rest of the app; they will always be in Portrait mode. The code pointed to by that blog also shows a mechanism to host common UI inside the root frame so you don't need to use a popup (look at App.Xaml and the ApplyCustomFrameTemplate method in the .cs file).

Comment: RootFrame is not there in wp8

Comment: I got the answer,To navigate from a UserControl, use this: ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(...);